# ASP.NET MVC4 DataAnnotations Validation on Models acting very strange - validating all fields even when I only specify one field to be validated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

To keep this real simple, I have a model that has just one Required attribute (just on the Name).  My View only has one `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` that's tied to the Name.  When I click Save on the View when nothing is filled in, all fields come back as required.  If I fill in the Name field, the remaining fields come back as required.  I really need some help figuring out why this is:

```
public class KeyActive
{
    [Key]
    public int Pk { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name of filler is required.")]
    [Display(Name="Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Capsule 00 Pack Stat:")]
    public int PackStat00 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Capsule 0 Pack Stat:")]
    public int PackStat0 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Capsule 1 Pack Stat:")]
    public int PackStat1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Capsule 3 Pack Stat:")]
    public int PackStat3 { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my View:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackStat00)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackStat00)
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackStat0)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackStat0)
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackStat1)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackStat1)
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackStat3)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackStat3)
</div>
```

Finally, when I fill out the form and click Save, here's what I get:

[image]

It's acting like every field is required- when I fill in Name, and leave everything else blank, it won't let me submit it because it seems to think the other fields are also required.  I really need some help figuring out if there's another place that I'm not seeing that performs validation, or what I'm doing wrong here!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be because your ViewModel is using int instead of a nullable value:

```
public Nullable<int> PackStat00
```

or

```
public int? PackStat00
```

Right now, there's no way to store a null value in your view model for those fields.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks!  I'll mark this as the correct answer when I'm able to.

Comment: Yep. This is the issue. There's an implicit "required" validation on the int fields since they're non-nullable and have no default values.

Comment: Its better not to think of it as an implicit required attribute. Its more accurate to say that this is a model binding validation error. The binder is telling you that attempting to cast a null string as an int is failing, hence the validation error. You would see the same effect if you typed "Dog" into one of those Editors.